# how to setPadding and background in runtime with performance?

Tags: android

I want to have a speed performance

```
mainLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));

curlContainerLayout.setPadding(5, 35, 5, 25);
```

my problem is slow changing in this code

could any one know a trick to make it fast ?

thanks in advance

Edit :
i use the above code in textview on afterTextChanged listener

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Looper.prepare();
                            myCurlActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    CurlActivity.tvCurrentPageNumber.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentIndex + 1));
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();
```

Comment: Store the drawable in a variable and reuse that variable instead of referring and creating it again and again

Comment: what about setPadding it is slow in runtime